# How to create your own maven dependency? Is it mandatory to have a main class in that jar?

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I only have few custom annotations and a few classes **in the test folder** that needs to be packaged into a jar so that I can use it as a dependency in another project. But when I try to run a mvn clean install, the build is failing with this error:

```
Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.8:repackage failed: Unable to find main class
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: You have the spring boot dependency that repackages your code.  Remove that.

Comment: Furthermore, move the classes to `src/main/java`.

Comment: @JFabianMeier, I have junit dependency in of the classes. So I can't move the classes to src/test/java

Comment: Move the classes to `src/main/java` and declare `junit` with scope `compile`.

Answer (score -1):

It needs a class containing a main method and annotated with the @SpringBootApplication.
if you have downloaded from start.spring.io, Windows would probably removed the .java file while un-zipping due to security violation.